# Should I modify my DTD if I use PHP in a web page?

Tags: php, html, dtd

I always include the following DTD on my web pages:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

I want to start using PHP on one of my sites. Should I modify this DTD in any way in order for it to remain valid?

And is there any reason why I should **not** use PHP blocks before the DTD or should the DTD always be the very start of each file?

Comment: How does the use of PHP change your HTML syntax?

Comment: PHP runs on the server. The resulting HTML should be unaffected by that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you should, not because you're using PHP, but because you should be using HTML5 these days.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

The doctype does not have anything to do with PHP at all, as it is a serverside language. The doctype will however affect the HTML you output.

Some browsers (read: IE) could have issues if ANY characters are outputted before the doctype, and using PHP before the doctype is'nt normally a problem, just make sure there are no empty space or linebreaks outputted in the HTML before the doctype.

Comment: @Pekka - slow typer (me), needs to finish !!

Comment: An opinion relating to the choice of doctype is not related to the question at all.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Yes, but it is friendly advice. Is this site not about learning and gaining experience from others???

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela No answer to that?

Answer (score 2):

Php is a server side language which generates text for the browser.  The browser interprets HTML text exactly the same regardless of how the HTML was generated.  Hard-coded html is interpreted in the browser the same as ASP-generated HTML, which is interpreted the same as PHP-generated HTML.

So your `Doctype` does **not** need to be customized based on any choice of server-side scripting language.

Answer (score 1):

### In brief

The `DOCTYPE` has nothing to do with PHP, it is what is returned to the browser that you need to be aware of.

### Detailed Answer

The `DOCTYPE` simply tells the browser how to interpret the page and the code that makes up the page. As `PHP` is a server side language, it has nothing to do with this, unless of course you are outputting specific HTML that requires a different `DOCTYPE` to the one you have defined.

### Credit

@adeneo has rightly added that you should alter it, but not because it has anything to do with PHP. For HTML 5 you must declare the doctype using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP outputs HTML (or other browser displayable content).  As long as the HTML that is output complies with your doctype, you can continue to use the doctype you've chosen.  If you're not aware of what a doctype is and does, here is an old but good reference: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/doctype/

Answer (score -1):

The choice of server-side technology used to generate pages does not affect the choice of doctype as such. What matters is the markup that gets sent to browsers.

The doctype statement (not a DTD – it’s in principle a reference to a DTD, though browsers don’t treat it that way) should be at the very start of an HTML document, but this applies to the HTML document sent to browsers. A .php file is not really an HTML document (or need not be), and any PHP instructions at the start are to be processed by server-side code and never reach a browser.